# How to trigger a variable/method in python from a html file with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to have a hyperlink on a html page run a variable that is defined in my python file. The variable is going to clear my database. Here is the code I am trying to use.

**Python**

```
@app.route('/log')
def log():
cleardb = db.session.delete()
return render_template('log.html', cleardb=cleardb)
```

**Html**

```
<a onclick="myFunction()">Clear database</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function myFunction()
</script>
```

I don't know what javascript I need to run the variable. I want to make the cleardb get triggered so that it will delete the database.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this question is *way* too broad. Rather, let JavaScript call another route via ajax.

Comment: Database record deletion cannot normally be done by Javascript due to it being a client-side language. What you want done, needs to be done server-side with PHP, Python, Java etc. Since you're using Python, you want to somehow send a request onClick back to your Flask-Python script.


Your best bet would be using Jquery/Javascript to send a request back to your python script and using the *request* module to 'grab' it. Treating it as a flag for deletion.

Comment: @Joseph Thank you for the information! I will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an ajax request with javascript to /log, it would look something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
          if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              //Do Success functionality here
          }
          else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
            //Handle 400 errors here
          }
          else {
            //All other errors go here
          }
       }
   };

   xmlhttp.open("GET", "/log", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```